# What are the different RDBMS source to which Sqoop can connect for importing the data and what is their connection syntax?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am learning Sqoop and I have a query. What are the different RDBMS source to which Sqoop can connect for importing the data and what is their connection syntax.

For eg, in case of MySQL, connection string can be specified as jdbc://mysql//Databasename.
For SQl Server, it needs to be specified as jdbc://sqlserver/servername:portnumber;database=databse_name.

Could some please help me in knowing what are the different style in which such connection string could be supplied to Sqoop. Please do share a guide or link for the same if you have any with the above information.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you

HSQLDB          1.8.0+                              jdbc:hsqldb:*//

MySQL           5.0+                                jdbc:mysql://

Oracle          10.2.0+                             jdbc:oracle:*//

PostgreSQL  8.3+                jdbc:postgresql://

More Details at https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.1-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#_supported_databases